# Putting multiple images together into one

Tags: java, image, graphics

I have bunch of photos sorted in a folder so that there is always one photo of type `A` and one photo of type `B` immediately after that.

Unfortunately, some of them needed to be rotated and I did so using standard Windows file explorer.

What I need is to **combine each pair of photos A and B into new single photo so that the first source photo is displayed above the second**. Both photos have same width.

**Here is the code :**

```
    File first = ...;
    File second = ...;

    BufferedImage A = ImageIO.read(first);
    BufferedImage B = ImageIO.read(second);

    int resultHeight = A.getHeight() + B.getHeight();
    int resultWidth = A.getWidth();
    BufferedImage combined = new BufferedImage(resultWidth, resultHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);


    Graphics g = combined.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(A, 0, 0, null);
    g.drawImage(B, 0, A.getHeight(), null);
    g.dispose();

    ImageIO.write(combined, "PNG", new File(destDirectory, destName));
```

Unfortunately, although all pictures seem to have same orientation when viewing with the `Windows app`, they are rotated differently in the result photos. I know there is some kind of flag that seems to be ignored by the `BufferedImage.`

**How can I detect that flag and eventually rotate the photo as needed before combining? Thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use the [MetadataExtractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor) to get the orientation of the images. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905868/how-to-rotate-jpeg-images-based-on-the-orientation-metadata).

Comment: If you extract the rotation you can use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749121/java-image-rotation-with-affinetransform-outputs-black-image-but-works-well-whe) to rotate the image.

Comment: Thanks! I used that library and it seems promising.